# How to Provide InvokeRESTAPI's Task Request Body Programmatically in Azure Devops YAML Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to Send a RestApi (With Callback capability) Post Request to do some integrations.

decided to use **InvokeRESTAPI@1** which is Agentless task. so i put it in a agentless job (server job).

the task's request body is a **output.json** file provided and published in a *PublishBuildArtifacts@1* task in previous job.

how to place the output.json in **InvokeRESTAPI@1**'s Body? is there any way to use a agent-based output in an agentless job? if not so how to provide **InvokeRESTAPI@1**'s boy programmatically?

Here is my pipeline for more details:

```
jobs:
- job: 'GetReleaseNotes'
  pool:
    name: MehdiPool
  steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        filePath: 'ReleaseNotesPipelines/pipeline-scripts/3_PostUpdates.ps1'
        arguments: >
          -PAT $(PAT)
          -ProjectName $(System.TeamProject)
          -ReleaseNotesRepo "ReleaseNotes"
          -Since $(Since)
          -Until $(Until)
      displayName: 'Create Post Data'
      name: 'CreatePostData'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output.json'
        ArtifactName: 'ReleaseNotesJson'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
      displayName: 'Upload Notes for Next Job'
- job: 'SendReleaseNotes'
  dependsOn: GetReleaseNotes
  pool: server
  steps:
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    inputs:
      buildType: 'current'
      downloadType: 'single'
      artifactName: 'ReleaseNotesJson'
      downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      cleanDestinationFolder: true
    displayName: 'Download Notes to WorkingDir'
  - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
      serviceConnection: 'CustomerPortal_ReleaseNotes_Post_Api'
      method: 'POST'
      body: |
        $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output.json
      waitForCompletion: 'true'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, an agentless task doesn't execute on a machine, so there isn't a place to download published build artifacts. I think the intended purpose of the `InvokeRestApi@1` task would be to asynchronously poll an endpoint and evaluate the outcome, like waiting for the status of an external integration, or waiting for a long running Azure operation to complete. This is similar to building custom [Approvals + Checks through a function-app or REST-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/invoke-checks?view=azure-devops), which are used to query integrations before the pipeline executes. In contrast, the `InvokeRestApi@1` task allows you to pause the pipeline mid-execution and resume after polling operation completes.

In your scenario, you're using the `InvokeRestApi@1` task to reuse authentication information from a service connection instead of placing those secrets as variables in the pipeline, which is a good idea. It's a shame that this task can only be used as an agentless pool.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, you'll want to use the [Logging Syntax to create an *Output* variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable), and then [reference that variable in the other job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job). It is important that you set dependencies between the two jobs, so that you can refer to the previous stage.

```yaml
- job: GetReleaseNotes
  steps:

  # your steps to produce the JSON
  - ... produce the json

  # Step to convert the JSON into a pipeline variable
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Read release notes'
    name: ReadReleaseNotes # we need a name for the task
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
         # in the event that your JSON isn't compressed, we'll 
         # read the JSON back into memory and flatten it down as much
         # as possible using the -Compress option
         $json = Get-Content "$(Build.StagingDirectory)\output.json" -Raw |
                 ConvertFrom-Json
         $text = ConvertTo-Json $json -Depth 100 -Compress

         # create a variable that can be used by other jobs
         Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ReleaseNotes;isOutput=true]$text"

- job: SendReleaseNotes
  displayName: 'Send Release Notes'
  pool: server
  dependsOn: # necessary to be able to reference job dependencies
  - GetReleaseNotes 

  steps:
  - task: InvokeRestApi@1
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
      serviceConnection: 'CustomerPortal_ReleaseNotes_Post_Api'
      method: 'POST'      
      body: $[ dependencies.GetReleaseNotes.outputs['ReadReleaseNotes.ReleaseNotes'] ]
      waitForCompletion: 'true'
```

Comment: thank you for all the details you mentioned and described. my problem solved.